# Print a float number in normal form, not exponential form / scientific notation

Tags: python, python-3.x, floating-point

I have a number that prints out in exponential form:

```
>>>
>>> a = 1/1221759
>>> print(a)
8.184920266599223e-07
>>>
```

How can i make it print in normal form?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You can format it as a fixed-point number.

```
>>> a = 1/1221759
>>> '{0:.10f}'.format(a)
'0.0000008185'
```

Comment: returns '0.0000000000' for me?

Comment: @Nik because Python 2.7 returns int with `/` operator. Py3 returns float. Put a decimal point at the end of `1221759`

Answer (score 11):

You can use print formatting:

```
print "%.16f" % a
```

where 16 is the number of digits you want after the decimal point.